# Django Migration: django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column:

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

Whenever I add a new column to my model I get:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: companies_company.[name of added column]

For example, I just added "employee_count" and whenever I run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I get:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: companies_companyadmin.employee_count

My model.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

import csv

class Company(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=1200, blank=True)
   employee_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True)


class CompanyAdmin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1200, blank=True)
    employee_count = models.(blank=True)

with open("organizationTest.txt","rU") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            _, created = Company.objects.get_or_create(
                name=row[3].decode('latin-1').encode('utf8'),
                description=row[15].decode('latin-1').encode('utf8'),
                )
```

The CSV part is simply to populate my DB (I should probably do it somewhere else).

And my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Company


class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.register(Company, CompanyAdmin)
```

This also happens when I try to run the server or "syncdb".

If anyone knows why this is happening and how I could fix this I would love to know! Thanks in advance! I'm happy to answer any questions you may have.

Comment: Did you run the migrate command after you added that column?

Comment: Yes! I ran it after I added the column!

Comment: @e4c5 Do you think you know why this is happening?

Comment: Such errors are usually seen because the django_migrations table isn't in sync with the actual migrations.

Comment: Please see if this works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32430112/267540

Comment: **Exactly** where is that CSV code in the model.py? Is it at module level?

Comment: @e4c5 I am using SQLite.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The CSV code is right after the top part. So right after I describe "CompanyAdmin".

Comment: What? You said it was in the model.py. Which file is it in, and (once again) ***exactly*** where in that file is it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have edited the question to show where is exactly is!

Comment: The fact that you are using sqlite and the other question is for mysql does not make any difference. Django is database agnostic

Comment: @e4c5 I tested it out again and it doesn't work! I get the same "No Such Column" error.

Comment: You are killing yourself by loading that data in models.py https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/ anyway what exactly does your table look like now?

Comment: @e4c5 How can I check how my table looks?

Comment: What makes me think that you haven't actually tried the solution proposed in the other question? If you had done so you would already know how to find out what a table looks like. Well since this is sqlite just double click on the database file you will see all the tables.

Comment: @e4c5 Do you want a screenshot? Also I can't even start the other solution because I get an error for the first commend.

Comment: First please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask getting an error is obviously not a very usefull comment. No I do not want a screenshot. Just look at your table and see if it corresponds to the model. And have you removed that CSV stuff before trying again?

Comment: I am having the same problem as OP.  running `makemigrations` or `migrate --fake` I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an initial value in some Querysets of an updated model. When I removed these initial statements, makemigrations had worked.

Answer (score -1):

Appears my original answer wasn't clear enough.

`Company.objects.get_or_create(
                name=row[3].decode('latin-1').encode('utf8'),
                description=row[15].decode('latin-1').encode('utf8'),
                )`

This block is out of a class so it runs when the server is started or basically everytime manage.py is run. `Company.objects.get_or_create(...)` is trying to run, on the updated database model that can't be created yet. To make the migrations you have to comment this line out, then make the migrations, then it will work.

Comment: This sounds like to much guessing. When you reach 50 rep you can comment to ask for clarifications. Until then, answer questions that does not need that.